# Can we deconfigure the [configuration] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Currently, 137 questions are tagged [configuration](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration). No tag wiki, no usage guidance.

The tag sort of begs the question - configuration of *what*? I think these questions ought to be tagged with that instead, and most of them already are.

Could we just take this tag out back and shoot it?

Answer (score 2):

Considering that misconfiguration of pretty much everything and anything is a big security issue - e.g. even in the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_A6-Security_Misconfiguration) - not to mention the challenges of scalable management of such configurations which lead to the above - I would say to keep it.

Of course we should probably get some descriptions and guidance on that...

Comment: Is a question about configuring Apache better if it is tagged with both configuration and apache, instead of just apache? There are no configuration experts, there are apache experts. But I'm fine with keeping it if it can get some proper usage guidance.

Comment: I dont think the question is necessarily better per se, but if someone is looking for configuration issues irrelevant of product would make findability easier. E.g. hypothetically talking about configuration management.

Comment: Hmm perhaps we should change the tag name to [tag:configuration-management] …. ?

Comment: Yeah, I like that tag better. I'll go through some questions and "mentally" retag them to see it it works in practice.

Comment: I went through th 30 latest question in the tag. I think the [tag:configuration-management] would fit around eight of them. (Five of those were about how to deal with secrets in configuration files.) Among the other 22 I found no common denominator, other than that they all deal with a piece of software that can be configured.